# Lyx does not export postscript file!

Tags: lyx, postscript

I try to export a lyx file to .ps format. But while I hit the save button I got the following error:
"No information to export the format Postscript"
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: By "save button"  you mean File > Export > postcript? It work perfectly for me, so I guess that your lyx cannot find the converter, that in Linux is `dvips` (convert a TeX DVI file to PostScript).

Comment: Yes after I try to export it as .ps format I got an error. So what do you suggest me to do? How can I define the converter for lyx?

Comment: Really do you need the obsolete DVI > PS or DVI>PS > PDF route? Today you can render as PDF directly and use `pdftops` in case that  you need to convert to pS. Anyway, export as DVI  and then without LyX, try to convert the DVI to PS. If this  work, see that the configuration in LyX Tools > Preferences > File handling > Converters is `dvips -o $$o $$i` and reconfigure.  In other case, you will need install the `dvips`  or check the system paths so LyX can find the converter.